# Remove text after clicking in the textbox?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

When you click on the textbox in order to make input data, I want to remove the previous text automatically for first time only?

Comment: Look to be a stackoverflow one. Are you talking about placeholder?http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder

Comment: No, i am getting the previous entered data into the text field. Now after i am clicking the textbox previous data will be erased and new entered will show.

Comment: So you're editing a previously saved page that's already populated with data? I believe what you're asking for is counter to normal browser functionality unless you were to create a JS or JQ function to clear the field "onClick"; something many might find annoying if they clicked into the wrong field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783604/how-to-clear-textarea-on-click) for ideas.

I suggest you add the following onFocus attribute to the text field element:

```
onFocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) { this.value = ''; }"
```

The conditional means that the textarea will only be emptied if its content is its default content (e.g. 'example' in `<textarea>example</textarea>`, and not if it's been updated.

Comment: Note that once you get this working, you should probably refactor it to separate the JS from the HTML / VF markup.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup

Comment: Hi Rob, small change in requirement, when you place cursor in textbox then the text visible in textbox will selected and when try to type the text, the previous text will be delete and new entered text will show. This is for first time only like previous. I tried with onkeyup but it's not worked.

Comment: Find this one also. I am used onkeypress(), it's worked.